# Получение сообщений из беседы

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно получить два айди сообщений из одной беседы, запускаю код ниже

```py
getmsgs=vk.messages.getHistory(count=2, peer_id=2000000245)
print(getmsgs)
```

Выдается содержимое в виде json схемы:

```
{'count': 9195, 'items': [{'date': 1580375452, 'from_id': 266501188, 'id': 3028264, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 2000000245, 'text': 'Еуе это глаз', 'conversation_message_id': 9369, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}, {'date': 1580375442, 'from_id': 266501188, 'id': 3028263, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 2000000245, 'text': 'Раскрываю прикол', 'conversation_message_id': 9368, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False, 'reply_message': {'date': 1580375265, 'from_id': 532076510, 'text': 'Eye скачай.', 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 9366, 'peer_id': 2000000245, 'id': 3028261}}]}
```

Теперь вывожу conversation_message_id с помощью print и дается только один айди сообщения, вопрос в том, как я выведу второй айди сообщения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
for item in getmsgs['items']:
    print(item['conversation_message_id'])
```